# Customizing a view in only some perspectives

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP application that uses the Project Explorer view in two perspectives. I have also customized the Project Explorer view by hiding some context menu entries and filtering the displayed file types.

Is it possible to show the customized Project Explorer in one view, but keep the default one (i.e. without my customization) in the other view?

Comment: How are you doing this customization?

Comment: I'm using activities to hide UI elements, and the INavigatorFilterService (called from a class extending WorkbenchWindowAdvisor) to filter the displayed files.

Comment: For activities you could try using the `enabledWhen` attribute and look the value of the `activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective` variable.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, that sounds like it could work. I'll give it a try.